# How can I make a user template for OSX which automatically makes user folders on a separate partition?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, user-profiles, disk-image

I have setup a default user template on a computer which I am building an Image for our fleet of Macbook Retinas.

We are using 10.8 and I have created the default user and moved it to the usertemplate/english.lproj which has worked fine.

However I need to configure it so that when a new domain user logs in their home folder is created on another volume.

I have tried creating Symlinks to Documents, Pictures, Movies etc in the user template so that users would be always directed to save there.

(This makes re imaging their computer easier as we dont have to back up the second partition).

However doing this seems to stuff all the permissions and the user can no longer access any thing, they cannot even save to their desktop.

What am i doing wrong?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define the home-path for your users so that when they log in the home-folder is created on that location. It should look something like /Network/Servers/[servername]/Volumes/[volumename]/[path/to/userfolder].

That way you will not need to use symlinks or magic to mount certain volumes on systemstart.